In a tabular with p-column, line spacing after multi-line cell too short with the array package
With the following MCE, the line spacing after the multi-line cell (“Lorem 2” → “Ipsum 2”) is the same as after mono-line cell (“Lorem 1” → “Ipsum 1”):
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{.25\linewidth}}
  {\Huge Lorem 1\par}       \\[.25cm]
  Ipsum 1                   \\[1cm]
  {\Huge Lorem Lorem 2\par} \\[.25cm]
  Ipsum 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


But as soon as the array package is loaded, the line spacing after multi-line cell is much shorter than after mono-line cell:

Why and is it possible to get the same line spacing even with array loaded?
(Note that the same trouble arises with the tabularx package as it loads array.)

The difference arises from the \par commands, which I would omit (why do you use them?). Then the tabular behaves the same with/without array. You can also omit the braces, as every cell is a separate group. What is the layout that you want to achieve?

@gernot Indeed, the braces are not necessary and without them, no need of \par and the problem doesn't arise anymore. With these braces (that I thought necessary), \par was necessary in order to avoid collision between lines.

The space specified in the optional argument to \\[..] applies to the whole row, and theoretically should not depend on the order of columns so if you had
{c p{5cm}} or {p{5cm} c} you might expect that the argument worked the same way. But the implementation in fact works by adding a strut to the last column, with the strut depth increased by the specified amount.  In the original definition, if the last column is a p column that ends in vertical mode, the \strut ends up in a paragraph on its own so almost all the space shown is spurious, even an extra 1sp would force a new line.  You could omit the braces and \par in this case, so your p columns did not end in vertical mode, but that is not always possible in real examples.
array tries to normalise out some of the quirks but it's a tricky area and basically hard to make the standard syntax do anything intuitive for p columns especially multi-line p columns where the strut is being added to the baseline of the row so on the top line of the paragraph.
A far more natural spacing is given by \\ \noalign{\vspace{.25cm}}  which simply adds the specified amount of space, booktabs package \addlinespace is essentially the same.  The reason LaTeX adds space via a strut and then has to go through hoops to try to put the strut in a sensible place is to avoid breaking vertical rules, but if, like booktabs package, you don't care about vertical rules, this is a far simpler and more direct way of specifying additional space..
